# calling class method on thread function

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have a class method isConnected(socket soc) which will return true if the socket is connected or false if isn't.I want to call it in two running thread with the same thread function.
is it not safe?

since I know that the method itself is reside in memory and it's share along the thread, so if one thread call isConnected method and it's running the other thread must not call it until the first thread finish with the method.

and I passing variable socket from thread to the isConnected method

Comment: _"since I know that the method itself is reside in memory and it's share along the threa"_ - that the code for a method resides in RAM once doesn't mean it can be executed concurrently where each caller has its own stack. If the `IsConnected()` method doesn't access variables outside its scope, it most probably is thread safe.

Comment: the problem is. I passing variable from the thread to this method,
so it's outside it's scope,right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the method uses some shared resources then it's safe because it will create local variables on its own stack and won't share it with the other thread.

But be aware that one thread can return true and the other false, because one can find a socket closed and the other can find it still open.

So it's not really a good idea to call it from two thread at one time.

Comment: I pass socket variable from thread to the method and I'm aware if the method will replace the old socket with new socket he got from the newest thread since the method is shared

Comment: Methods are not shared, but the socket can be. And if you have only one socket object that you pass to both threads then it can go bang. But if each of the threads use its own socket, than it all right.

Comment: thanks, I have just known that, so do you mean for each call, the function will create it's own stack?

Comment: No, each thread has its own stack where it stores local variables. Method is only something that operates with this variables. But you can have a resource, say your socket, that was created on the main thread and passed to two new threads so they can work with it and therefore it's a shared resource - if the first changes it then the second will see it changed.